# How to implement pop up window in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

can,anyone tell how to implement popup window(same tab) in asp.net mvc 2.0?

i tried this jquery code

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this)
                .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                    modal: true,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 900,
                    left: 0

                })
                .load(this.href);
     });

     $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
     });
```

scripts:

But it not works..

Comment: Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: Obvious question, but have you included both jQuery and jQuery UI in the page?

Comment: @andrew: object[object object] has no method 'dialog'

Comment: It sounds like either you have them the wrong way round (jQuery must come first), or you're using incompatible versions.  Try using the 3 urls in "quick access" at the bottom left of this page... http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Can you post the code of your view please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI dialog, here it is a working example of [Edit data in dialog form with JQuery and Asp.Net MVC](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/edit-data-in-dialog-form-with-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: How does that page solve the error "object[object object] has no method 'dialog'"?

Comment: It solves the problem because it's an working example of jQUery UI dialog, if you'll look at the project, you'll see that, in the view, jquery script is loaded before the ui, and both scrips match the required version.